# How to surpass the Y/N command in google collab shell command?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

so I have command which ask the `Found 1 job(s). Submit? [y/N]:` in google collab but how can I enter Y or N in collab shell command automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What command are you running?
`yes` command maybe the one you may looking for. I don't know what your command is but here is example:
`yes | apt-get update`.

You can also run `yes --help` to see more option

A similar question can be found here [How do I automatically answer y in bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/512367/how-do-i-automatically-answer-y-in-bash-script). The bash script in the question is just commands only, so you can take it as example.

Comment: `yes --help` will keep printing `--help` to `stdout`.